# For Mac OS sometimes the "command" + "backtick" doesn't cycle through all of the windows of an application

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts

I find that sometimes when I am trying to cycle through open windows of an application with "command" + "backtick" it will only move through a few of them and then go back to the first. The other windows are not minimized or in different spaces. I find it happens most often with my LaTeX editor/previewing/console windows (I use TeXshop). And its not all the time, but I haven't noticed yet if some behavior as I am working that suddenly causes it.

Just wondering if anyone else has had this sort of issue. Its not a huge problem, but it can get annoying sometimes when I need to switch back and forth a lot between the file I am writing in and the file I have to be active on to compile. Thanks!

Comment: According to http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/147905/using-command-backtick-to-toggle-between-windows, the order changes when you click.

Answer (score 3):

Coming from Windows and Linux, the <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Backtick</kbd> of Macos feels half baked and annoying to me.

Luckily there's an amazing Open source alternative Alt-Tab!!

Here's the link:  https://alt-tab-macos.netlify.app/

I've installed this and it's really awesome.
It has options for both all apps alt-tabbing as well as apps of one single app with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Backtick</kbd>.

Also <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>backtick</kbd> works even if all windows of one app are not in same desktop.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest if you want to cycle between all application windows including the minimized windows is to enable it through System pref - Mission Control - Application windows - select your preferred keyboard short cut (I am using Control + down arrow).

Also, to do the same with mouse is to assign certain corner through System pref -- Mission Control -- Hot corners - select your desired corner and assign it to application windows.

Comment: So the keyboard shortcut is set and works most of the time, just every once in a while it won't move through all the windows of an application, say only 3 of 6 open (all the same application).

Comment: you mean it didn't cycle between all application windows using the newly assigned short cut? would you please tell me which app cause this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

I have seen an issue like this recently; in Photoshop, Command-Backtick seemed to work only intermittently.

Today, I discovered that when I have my keyboard language set to Maori (to add diacritical marks to names in my SF novel), hitting Command-Backtick apparently does not send the same ASCII code as the US English keyboard.

Try checking your keyboard language in System Settings > Keyboard > Input Sources. Setting it back to US English instantly fixed it for me.